# How to remove mutiple edges in gremlin query

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I created a edge called "created" between **User** vertex and **Event** vertex

```
 user1(8312) ---created---> event1(1234)

 user1(8312) ---created---> event2(4567)

 user1(8312) ---created---> event3(7890)
```

I can delete one edge at a time,but if I want to delete mutiple edges have to loop though and hit multple db calls.Is there any way to delete mutiple edges at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to drop edges between multiple vertices then you could do something like this:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V(1).outE()
==>e[9][1-created->3]
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
gremlin> g.V(1).outE().where(inV().hasId(within(2,3))).drop()
gremlin> g.V(1).outE()
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
```

You can read more about this in [Gremlin Recipes](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#between-vertices).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how you remove the edges, but if you simply want to remove all outgoing *created* edges from the vertex with the ID *8312*, then this should work:

```
g.V(8312).outE('created').drop().iterate()
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, though it's worth noting that this is still looping through each edge to drop it. I'm not aware of any graph database implementation that can optimize that bit of Gremlin to avoid doing that.

Comment: If I given outE("created").drop() all the edges will be dropped.I want to drop edges between two specific vertex

Comment: This the query for removing edge between two vertices

Comment: g.V(1).bothE().where(otherV().hasId(2)).drop()   but for mutiple vertices.is there any way?